# Using SoapService Class with WCF web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I need to create a web service to receive a SOAP request that a customer uses to send out information to various systems, all I have is an example xml payload. I have created a test WCF web service using
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-simple-wcf-service-and-host-it-on-console-application/
and was going to just create a class along the lines of

```
public class WebServiceSOAP : IWebServiceSOAP
{
    public string SetProductInfo(string strSOAPRequest)
    {
        // Parse the xml received, validate etc
        string response = ParseSOAPData(strSOAPRequest);
        // response depends on if data passes validation or not.
        return response;

    }
}
```

and host it in a console App. I then came across `SoapService` Class during my googling but I am not clear on how this fits in with a normal WCF service as the example here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms819935.aspx

seems to use `Microsoft.Web.Services2/3` instead of `System.ServiceModel` does this mean I can use the same method to set up my webservice as the example I have previously followed? Including the App.config. The example seems for `System.ServiceModel` seems completely different to the setup of the WCF service I followed. I am clearly missing something. I can't inherit from both the interface and `SoapService`, plus I would have a function with a `[OperationContract]` and a `[SoapMethod]` attribute.

It looks like I could receive the SOAPEnvelope and use `SoapEnvelope.GetBodyObject` to get the body / payload but I am not clear if it returns xml or if the body still has all the < replaced with < etc Can I just take the result of `SoapEnvelope.GetBodyObject` and parse the xml?

Comment: You don't need a WCF service to be a client of a WCF service and I would recommend you not since WCF can be pretty complicated. If you don't have a wsdl or endpoint you can use to generate a proxy then can always just parse the soap as xml.

Comment: I am not being the client. I need to be the service. The customer already has another contractor onsite who uses a web service that receives soap request. We also need to receive the same request.